# how to condition tabs to be added to action bar or not

Tags: android, tabs, android-actionbar

i have five columns in my database and five tabs that each column corresponds to each tab
now i want to add tabs to actionbar just if the corresponding column was not empty
so how i should condition tabs to be shown or not depends on their corresponding columns
i used this strategy to condition tabs and it worked but unfortunately the name of tabs are not correct :

```
public class Content extends FragmentActivity implements ActionBar.TabListener {

private Gcontent g;
private String g_name;
private String g_family;
private String g_about;
private String g_age;
private String g_father;

private ActionBar actionBar;
private ViewPager viewPager;
private TabsPagerAdapter tabsAdapter = new TabsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_pc_content);

    g = (Gcontent) getIntent().getExtras().get("CurrMember");
    g_name = g.getGname();
    g_family = g.getGfamily();
    g_about = g.getGabout();
    g_age = g.getGstory();
    g_father = g.getGfather();

    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.tabs_container);
    viewPager.setAdapter(tabsAdapter);

    actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
    actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(false);


    if(!(g_name.equals("empty"))){
        actionBar.addTab(
            actionBar.newTab().
            setText("first tab").
            setTabListener(this)
        );
    }

    if(!(g_family.equals("empty"))){
        actionBar.addTab(
            actionBar.newTab().
            setText("second tab").
            setTabListener(this)
        );
    }

    if(!(g_about.equals("empty"))){
        actionBar.addTab(
            actionBar.newTab().
            setText("third tab").
            setTabListener(this)
        );
    }

    if(!(g_age.equals("empty"))){
        actionBar.addTab(
            actionBar.newTab().
            setText("fourth tab").
            setTabListener(this)
        );
    }

    if(!(g_father.equals("empty"))){
        actionBar.addTab(
            actionBar.newTab().
            setText("fifth tab").
            setTabListener(this)
        );
    }

    viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });

    viewPager.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            viewPager.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
            return false;
        }
    });

}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
public void onTabReselected(Tab arg0, FragmentTransaction arg1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction arg1) {
    viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());

}

@Override
public void onTabUnselected(Tab arg0, FragmentTransaction arg1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
}
```

and this is my pager adapter :

```
public class TabsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

int count;

public TabsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int index) {
    switch(index){
    case 0 :
        return new FragmentFirst();
    case 1 :
        return new FragmentSecond();
    case 2 : 
        return new FragmentThird();
    case 3 :
        return new FragmentFourth();
    case 4 :
        return new FragmentFifth();
    }
    return null;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return 5;
}

}
```

Comment: thats means automaticaly add tab after fetch databse?

Comment: whats result of `g` in `g = (Gcontent) getIntent().getExtras().get("CurrMember");` ?

Comment: that is a parceable object came from antoher activity by intents

Comment: please email me. pishguy@gmail.com